# what does the adverb "newly" modify in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, adverbs, modifiers

What does the adverb "newly" modify in this sentence?

> Certain Italians who were **newly** cognizant of Greek and Roman cultural accomplishments initiated a classical cultural rebirth after a long period of stasis.

Comment: It modifies "cognizant", the head of the AdjP "newly cognizant of Greek and Roman cultural accomplishments", which functions as predicative complement of "be".

Comment: @BillJ probably you are right. My mistake.

Comment: @BillJ Why a comment instead of an answer? That seems quite complete.

Answer (score 1):

It modifies "cognizant", the head of the Adjective phrase "newly cognizant of Greek and Roman cultural accomplishments", which functions as the predicative complement of "be".